# Asp:menu - submenu mouse out and delay hide time

Tags: asp.net, delay, aspmenu

I am using Asp.net menu control, and I try to delay the hiding of submenu items.

On submenu items when the mouse leaves the li element then the submenu disappears instantly.

But I want a 2 seconds delay.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution :

Go to the Properties of the Asp.Net Menu Control.

Find the DisappearAfter property.

Set the value in millisecond.